# Plotly Dash - TypeError: Object of type Polygon is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, geopandas, plotly

I am attempting to plot choropleth map using dash and mapbox. At runtime, I am getting an error `"TypeError: Object of type Polygon is not JSON serializable"`.

sample data and code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import fiona
from shapely import wkt
import dash
from dash import html
import geojson
import json

MAPBOX_KEY="pk.xxx...."
token = MAPBOX_KEY

url = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bP_SdwrU7pMtCPnOd5XfA3oQYKWYlNjn/view?usp=sharing"

df_geo = gpd.read_file(url)


layout = html.Div([
   
                    dcc.Graph(id="map"),
                    html.Div(id="dummy")

         ])


@app.callback(
              [

                Output("map", "figure")

              ],
              [

                Input("dummy", "value")
                          
              ],
             )
def update_map(d):

    s = df_geo['avg_price'].astype(float)

    datad = []

    datad.append({

                    "type": "choroplethmapbox",
                    "geojson": df_geo.__geo_interface__,
                    "locations": df_geo['tract'],
                    "z": s,
                    "featureidkey": "properties.tract",
                    "autocolorscale":False,
                    "colorscale":"YlOrRd",
                    "colorbar":dict(
                                    title = label,
                                    orientation = 'h',
                                    x= -0.15,
                                    xanchor= "left",
                                    y= 0,
                                    yanchor= "bottom",
                                    showticklabels=True,
                                    thickness= 20,
                                    tickformatstops=dict(dtickrange=[0,10]),
                                    titleside= 'top',
                                    ticks= 'outside'
                                   ),
                    "zmin": s.min(),
                    "zmax": s.max(),
                    "marker_line_width": 0,
                    "opacity": 0.2,
                    "labels": label,
                    "title": "Choropleth - Census Tract Level"

                 }
    )

    layout = {

              "autosize": True,
              "datarevision": 0,
              "hovermode": "closest",
              "mapbox": {

                 "accesstoken": MAPBOX_KEY,
                 "bearing": 0,
                 "center": {
                     "lat": 33.6050991,
                     "lon": -112.4052438
                 },
                 "pitch": 0,
                 "opacity": 0.2,
                 "zoom": zoom,
                 "style": "streets",

             },

             "margin": {
                "r": 0,
                "t": 0,
                "l": 0,
                "b": 0,
                "pad": 0
            }

       }

return ({"data": datad, "layout": layout})
```

Full Traceback:

```
Exception on /_dash-update-component [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dash/_callback.py", line 191, in add_context
    jsonResponse = to_json(response)
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dash/_utils.py", line 21, in to_json
    return to_json_plotly(value)
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/plotly/io/_json.py", line 124, in to_json_plotly
    return json.dumps(plotly_object, cls=PlotlyJSONEncoder, **opts)
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 234, in dumps
    return cls(
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_plotly_utils/utils.py", line 59, in encode
    encoded_o = super(PlotlyJSONEncoder, self).encode(o)
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_plotly_utils/utils.py", line 136, in default
    return _json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type Polygon is not JSON serializable


    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 1336, in dispatch
    response.set_data(func(*args, outputs_list=outputs_list))
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dash/_callback.py", line 193, in add_context
    _validate.fail_callback_output(output_value, output)
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dash/_validate.py", line 297, in fail_callback_output
    _validate_value(val, index=i)
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dash/_validate.py", line 287, in _validate_value
    _raise_invalid(
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dash/_validate.py", line 226, in _raise_invalid
    raise exceptions.InvalidCallbackReturnValue(
dash.exceptions.InvalidCallbackReturnValue: The callback for `[<Output `map.figure`>]`
returned a value having type `list` which is not JSON serializable.
```

Comment: You need to convert your polygon into a string before the json package can write it out. You may need to find a geojson writer instead

Comment: @IanTurton I updated the code based on a suggestion, no longer to download `geojson` twice, instead am using `__geo_interface__`. Do I still need to convert polygon to strings?

Comment: having the same problem. Did you find any solution?